# How to check to empty entry in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having problem with this, I have tried codes that work in other part of my program but this won't work correctly. I am coding to make sure a user does not submit ab empty form.

**Codes**

```
                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/msage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:hint="Write Something...."
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                   android:layout_margin="40dp"/>
```

Then on my Activity:

```
 EditText msg;
 msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msage);

 String msgContent =  msg.getText().toString().trim();
    if (msgContent.equals("") || msgContent.length() <= 15) {
        msg.setError("Enter valid Message");
        return;
    }

   //---below: code to submit form to server
```

I even tried `TextUtils.isEmpty`

**Edit**

So, after more than 12 hours of hair pulling, I finally found where the logic is wrong.

My code was encased in

```
public void btnSendFeedBack(View view) {
    // Code
}
```

using the `android:clickable="true" and android:onClick="btnSendFeedBack"`, but this was so wrong as I found out.

After been chased around by @Charuz, I changed to

```
findViewById(R.id.sendFeedback).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            msgContent = msg.getText().toString().trim();
            //email
            if (msgContent.equals("") || msgContent == null || msgContent.length() < 15) {
                msg.setError("Enter a valid Feedback");
                return;
            }

            SendFeedback();
        }
    });
```

And it worked.

Thanks for your time...cheers!!!

Comment: There is nothing wrong above, did you inputted it in the right edittext?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: The code fails to check for empty `edittext` and subsequently make the empty submit to server.

Comment: @BlackPearl can you post the full method or at least the body of it so can get a clear idea where it ends

Comment: @BlackPearl Also Note that you are also checking message length is less than 15 if yes ignore it why you use that? I dont see any problem there probably your are missing a basic thing that you havent posted here

Comment: @Charuක I want the text to be more than 15 characters

Comment: @BlackPearl I dont see any problem there but then for sure your getText gonna be "" so make sure your update to server method does not get called also if you dont have any text getText gonna be "" no need to mention android:text=""

Answer (score 2):

you have not added else condition for your code it checks for empty string and sends same to server.

```
   if (msgContent.equals("") || msgContent.length() <= 15) {
        msg.setError("Enter valid Message");
    }
    else
    {
//submit form to server
    }
```

Comment: Check the code above, there is `return;` to stop the process

Comment: it will return from if loop and send msgContent to server.

Comment: @BlackPearl, Check the answer I provided!

Answer (score 2):

Simply before sending form to server validate EditText value.

```
String val=EditText.getText().toString();
```

And inside your button click use logic,

```
if(val.length()>15){

  // Your logic for submit form to server
}else{
  // Error message as per your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple logic for checking if the `Edittext` is empty or not

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
    return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

in your code try this:

```
String msgContent =  msg.getText().toString().trim();
if ((msgContent.length() == 0) || (msgContent.length() <= 15)) {
    msg.setError("Enter valid Message");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Tried this before

Comment: `code fails to check for empty edittext and subsequently make the empty submit to server.` --apply this code it will return the process and submit will not be make..if not solved surely the problem lies somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Remove line in **EditText**:

```
 android:text=""
```

And try:

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(msg.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: Tried this before

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the condition `true` at first,  on `if` block and send data to server:

```
EditText msg;
msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msage);

String msgContent =  msg.getText().toString().trim();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msgContent) || msgContent.length() >= 15) {
    //Send data to server

}else{
   msg.setError("Enter valid Message");
   //return;
}
```

[Order of Evaluation of Logic Operators](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/46.html)

Comment: Tried this before

Comment: @BlackPearl this is kind of a spam you have tried all but nothing works! post your full code!!  there is no reason to go wrong of the every person answer here! you are doing a primary mistake and you are spamming

Comment: Once you try with the logic of mine answer, just don't say tried before. Try to implement the logic same as answer.

Comment: @Charuක, I tried this code and the logic is cool man, Don't know what OP what's charuka. No possibility of everyone's answer be wrong.

Comment: @Charuක Spam? Its a simple `Check for empty text` that I have implemented time and time again. It has nothing to do with server, everything happens before the server is being contacted.

Comment: @W4R10CK  yes I know even bellow answers there are if else conditions as the way he says it neither go to anyone!

Comment: @W4R10CK That's why it beats me, cause I used the same code to check for empty username and password, check for empty comment too.

Comment: @BlackPearl, Man frankly speaking this piece of code is working on India's top e-commerce app. Even in the hell, it will work. (Jokes Apart hahaha :D). Make sure to add your full code to see where our logics are failing.

Answer (score 0):

try with **addTextChangedListener** in your code.

```
    msg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //here you will get the state of edittext before a change took place
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            // here is the best place to check the length of the valu form edit text on the go.
            // check whether the length is greater than 15
            // and if yes send to server.
            //[ MAY BE A BOOLEAN FLAG CAN MAKE YOUR JOB MUCH EASIER]
            // Else you can show the error message

            if(msg.getText().length()>15){
                VALID_MESSAGE = true;
            }
            else{
                msg.setError("Enter valid Message");
                VALID_MESSAGE = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        }
    });
```

Here i have used a boolean VALID_MESSAGE. It becomes true when user input text with length greater than 15. Also make it false when he erase the entered text.
So while sending to server you just need check whether the **flag is true**.

The same can also be done inside **afterTextChanged**.
There is not much difference.